# Javascript trim newlines that are <br />s

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have the following code in a `<div>` tag:

```
<div id="something"><br /> <br />Hello<br />World<br><br />   </div>
```

How could I `trim` on the JS side so that it would trim out all of the white space and the HTML line breaks so I get something such as the following:

```
<div id="something">Hello<br />World</div>
```

Comment: That hasn't trimmed out all the line breaks, there is still one between `Hello` and `World`

Comment: P.S: you had an incorrect tag so I removed it : `</br />`

Comment: @roXon: `trim` works the same way, with spaces.

Comment: @DavidHedlund anyway `</br />` != `<br />`

Comment: Oops, my previous comment was meant to be in response to @Aesthete. Sorry

Comment: I've edited the question to take into consideration ```<br>```

Answer (score 4):

You can remove spaces and `<br />` nodes at the start and end of a string with

```
x = x.replace(/^( |<br \/>)*(.*?)( |<br \/>)*$/,"$2");
```

but you will have to apply this to the `innerHTML` of the div element.

Comment: ```x.replace(/^( |<br \/>|<br>)*(.*?)( |<br \/>|<br>)*$/,"$2")``` matchs also `<br>` tags. Elements with `contenteditable`, for example, adds `<br>` tags when user presses Enter.

Answer (score 1):

With a regex replace, it would be

```
return html.replace(/\s*(<br ?\/>\s*)+/g, "<br />").replace(/^<br \/>|<br \/>$/g, "");
```

In the DOM, you would need to loop over all children of the div and remove emtpy whitespaces and back-to-back `br` elements:

```
var el = document.getElementById("something");
for (var i=0, remove=true; i<el.childNodes.length; ) {
    var child = el.childNodes[i];
    if (child.nodeType == 3 && child.isElementContentWhitespace)
        el.removeChild(child);
    else if (child.nodeType == 1) {
        if (child.nodeName.toLowercase() == "br" && remove)
            el.removeChild(child);
        else
            // run DOM tree recursively?
        remove = true;
    } else {
       remove = false;
       i++;
    }
}
if (el.lastChild.nodeType == 1 && el.lastChild.nodeName.toLowercase() == "br")
    el.removeChild(el.lastChild);
```

Comment: This regex doesn't work for me, `a   <br>  b` becomes `a`

Comment: @Rudi: I cannot reproduce. `"a <br> b"` becomes `"a <br> b"` (no change), because it's missing the slash. `"a <br/> b"` becomes `"a<br />b"` as expected.

Comment: Sorry @Bergi my fault!